# Are there standalone libraries for Firefox Sync?

Tags: firefox

For example, I'd like to write a script that retrieves all my bookmarks that contain the word "html5" in the title, and adds the tag "web-development" to those bookmarks.

I know there is an [Client API specification](http://docs.services.mozilla.com/sync/index.html), but it seems like a complicated protocol, and I figure someone must have developed a library already. **It's hard to see which documentation  and libraries are up-to-date**. There's [this page on the Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Weave/Developer#Libraries), but it has this message:

> Warning: Most of the information on this page is outdated. Weave has been renamed Firefox Sync and is now part of Firefox 4. Many APIs documented here have evolved.

What's the current version of the Firefox Sync protocol used?

I've found [this code inside Android Sync](https://github.com/mozilla-services/android-sync/tree/develop/src/main/java/org/mozilla/gecko/sync) (a month old), and [weaveclient-python](https://github.com/mozilla/weaveclient-python) (2 years old). Are there any standalone libraries I can use in my own programs?

Answer (score 0):

It seems no stand-alone lib to use. You can also check shaman's project page
https://github.com/emergentdotorg/shaman

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a FirefoxData-android library which can help you to integrate an Android app with Firefox Sync https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/FirefoxData-android